# why and where to use the wordpress get_the_id() function

Tags: wordpress, function

I have started wordpress theme development and am confused why do we need this function please help me with simple real time example Thanks

Comment: Ain't an answer [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_ID)?

Answer (score 0):

[`get_the_ID`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_ID) **returns** the the post ID (so it doesn't have to be displayed in the HTML output), while  [`the_ID`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/the_ID) shows the ID in the HTML output.

This can be useful to reference the ID of the post, for example for a "Page Feedback form" or for using the ID in the HTML output somewhere.